Using PC Sync with Pocketwizard TT5 to trigger flash
I have tried using the PC sync ports on my LF Lens and a Mamiya 645 to rule out potential camera related issues. I'm trying to get the PC sync port to trigger flashes from a Pocketwizard TT5 Flex to other receivers. On a Canon/Hotshoe it works as expected.
I have set via the utility for the TT5 to work in basic trigger but I'm still not having any luck. All advice welcome.

Good Luck. My (admittedly limited) experience with PocketWizard products in general is that they sometimes work when they feel like it. It's been over a decade since far cheaper options with solid reliability have been available.

It functions as either a receiver or a transmitter, it does not do both simultaneously.
When set as a receiver it will trigger a flash mounted to it, it will not wirelessly trigger other flashes.

Where does the OP say it's set to 'receive' instead of 'transmit'. Every flash transmitter I've ever seen with a PC connection can transmit a "fire" signal when the PC circuit is completed.

@MichaelC,  he wants it to receive the trigger signal on the PC (3.5mm) port and then relay that wirelessly to other recievers. The P1 port is just a passthrough to the hotshoe (same as any transmitter I've used).

That's not a "receive" function. That's a switch, just like the hot shoe connector. "Receive" is a radio function, not a hard-wired one.
